# Forking react-scripts to add custom dependencies

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

Create React App docs suggest [forking react-scripts](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting) (instead of ejecting) if we have many similar projects. That's exactly my use case - I am trying to standardize the packages and structure that I always use in a React project. I would like to add these packages to the generated package.json file as opposed to the dependencies of react-scripts. For example, in the generated package.json file, the dependencies section should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
  "react": "^16.8.3",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.3"
},
```

It appears that the only way to do this is to modify create-react-app itself because the code that generates package.json resides [there](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L128-L142).

I know that the CRA team recommends against modifiying create-react-app itself. So is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: If your goal is to not make your team install all packages each time, we created an installation bat, which would first run create-react-app and then read the package.json file hosted some where and just install those packages.

Comment: Thanks, Sujit. That's a good approach. It would solve the packages problem. However, I was thinking of forking react-scripts anyway for overriding other minor things. It would be nice to do all this in one place.

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned, its very easy to implement. thanks a lot. have suggested it my company.